# C# convert .value to int

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

Im using the Mahapps.Metro framework for my C#, Wpf Application.
In the framework is the wpf element: [NumericUpDown](http://mahapps.com/controls/numericupdown.html).

Now I used the element like this:

```
<Controls:NumericUpDown Name="numCreateArticleStock" Minimum="0"/>
```

Now I want to convert the entered value in the field into a int value.

Here is my try:

```
int articleStock = 0;

if(!Int32.TryParse(numCreateArticleStock.Value, out articleStock)
{
    await this.ShowMessageAsync("Error", "Error - Message");
}
```

I get this error:

1. `Cannot convert "double?" in "string"`

---

Maybe someone of you have an Idea, Thanks!

Comment: Please provide *exact* error message...

Comment: What is the type of the `Value` property?  If' it's `double` then just cast it instead of trying to parse it.

Answer (score 5):

The error you get is because the `TryParse` method expects as `string` value, but you have a `double?` value.

There is no need to parse the value, you can just convert it from double:

```
int articleStock = (int)numCreateArticleStock.Value.GetValueOrDefault();
```

The `GetValueOrDefault` method will turn a `null` value into `0`, I assume that's what you want when there is no value to get from the control.

Answer (score 1):

Since `numCreateArticleStock.Value` is a `double?` why not just check if it is `null` and then cast it to `int` if it is not `null`.

```
int articleStock = 0;
if(!numCreateArticleStock.Value.HasValue)
{
    // value is null decide what to do in that case.
}
else
{
    articleStock = (int)numCreateArticleStock.Value.Value;
}
```